# How do I output a list of strings instead of [object : object]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, format

I was not able to output the list of names like **Bart, Lisa & Maggie** but had a list of **[object: object], [object, object] & [object, object]** instead.

Here is the code:

```js
let names = null;

function list(names) {
  return names.slice(0, names.length - 2).join(', ') + ', ' +
    names.slice(names.length - 2, names.length + 1).join(' & ');
}

console.log(list(names));
```

Comment: May you please share what `names` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `names` array looks like this :

```
const names = [{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]
```

I think you can do something like that :

```js
const names = [{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]

function list(names){
  let str = '';
  if (names.length !== 0) {
    // Get the last name and remove it from the names array
    let last = names.pop();

    if (names.length !== 0) { // names may be empty if there was only one value in the initial names array
      // Then you need to transform your array from [{name: 'Bart'},...]
      // to ['Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie'] :
      str = names.map( (val, i, arr) => {
        if (i !== arr[arr.length - 1]) {
          return val.name;
        }
      }).join(', ')
      // From here, str is equal to "Bart, Lisa"
      // Now we add "& Maggie" to the string
      str += ' & ' + last.name;
    }
  }

  return str;
}

console.log(list(names))
// "Bart, Lisa & Maggie"
```

(Edit) Or here is another way to do it, by keeping your initial code :

```js
const names = [{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'}]

function list(names){
  return names.slice(0, names.length - 2).map(value => value.name).join(', ') + ', ' +
    names.slice(names.length - 2, names.length + 1).map(value => value.name).join(' & ');
}

console.log(list(names))
// "Bart, Lisa & Maggie"
```

Comment: Hi, 

Would you please explain the reason to add .map() after I use slice to copy a part of the array into a new array?  I feel confused why I can't just use join () to put these array elements together and return as a new string? Thank you.

Comment: It's because when you slice you obtain an array containing objects, for example : `[{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]`. But an object can't be displayed as a string (that's why you get `[object: object]`), you want to display the `name` property of each object. So you use map() to convert `[{name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}]` into `['Bart', 'Lisa']`. I don't know if it is well explained

Comment: Now I understand why I kept having objects instead of a string. Thank you!